# Numpad point change to comma

Tags: c#, key, numpad

Is there a way to change the point from my numpad to a comma using C# in a NummericUpDown? Here in Europe we use a comma and not a point as decimal digit.

Answer (score 1):

you seam to have a WinForms application. you just need to use the correct locale. before any UI is displayed (in the Program class) change the CurrentCulture for the current thread. this should format your data the way you want. the code below shows an example.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

Comment: are you setting the culture before displaying the form? this should work. it was a while back but I remember doing a sample to test it before I gave the answer